# Why does proposing a compel against another player cost a fate point? [Nevermind]

Tags: fate, fate-accelerated, compels, fate-points

Fate Core p. 71

> Finally, and this is very important: **if a player wants to compel
>   another character, it costs a fate point to propose the
>   complication.** The GM can always compel for free, and any player can
>   propose a compel on his or her own character for free.

Say I'm a player. I notice an aspect that another player could compel, however, it seems I'm the only one who has noticed this possibility. I want to make the player and the GM aware of this, but I don't want to spend a fate point.

What's the purpose of this conflict of interest? What happens if a player suggests a compel and doesn't have any fate points left? Am I misunderstanding the rules?

EDIT: Oops, I read it as "compel another player" not as "compel another character" I don't know how I managed to mis-read it and mis-reread it several times.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can talk all you want. No law against that.

But the only thing that forces someone to spend a Fate Point or suffer appropriate plot consequences is you spending a Fate point yourself. (Or, you know, being a GM with an unlimited reserve.)

However, human beings also use language to communicate ideas to each other. If your fellow player agrees with the compel you brought up, they can propose it on themselves for free. It isn't somehow invalid for them to do that because you thought of it first.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the purpose of this conflict of interest?

Fate points represent the player's ability to change part of the game. They're also a limited resource.  The currency of Fate points is how Fate works the way it does.

> I want to make the player and the GM aware of this, but I don't want to spend a Fate point.

You could bring aspect up to the players and GM.  They don't have to act on it. Spending the Fate point *would* make them strongly consider acting on it (or spend a Fate point to reject it).

> What happens if a player suggests a compel and doesn't have any Fate points left?

Then it's just a suggestion. Without a Fate point, they can't make the compel. (Note that they also can't resist a compel.)